# Concatenação em PHP com DomPDF

Tags: php

Fala galera beleza ? Pra que eu possa mostrar todo o conteúdo em um PDF com o html eu preciso concatenar linha por linha, até aí tudo Ok. O problema é que quando eu tento colocar o método $_POST pra mostrar o conteúdo de um formulário dinâmico, me apresenta um erro:

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Emp\gerar_pdf.php on line 176
```

A linha que vem este erro é esta:

```
  $html .="<td>$_POST['interrupcao'][$i]</td>";
```

Aqui está um trecho do que estou tentando mostrar:

```
  $html .= "<table>";
  $html .= "<tr>";
  $html .= "<th>INTERRUPÇÕES</th>";
  $html .= "<th>Início</th>";
  $html .= "<th>Término</th>";
  $html .= "</tr>";
  $teste = $_POST['interrupcao'];
   for ($i=0; $i < count($teste); $i++) {
  $html .="<td>$_POST['interrupcao'][$i]</td>";
  $html .="<td>$_POST['inicioint'][$i]</td>";
  $html .="<td>$_POST['terminoint'][$i]</td>";
   }    
  $html .= "<tr>";
  $html .= "</tr>";
  $html .= "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve proteger variáveis com aspas usando chaves:

```
 $html .="<td>{$_POST['interrupcao'][$i]}</td>";
 $html .="<td>{$_POST['inicioint'][$i]}</td>";
 $html .="<td>{$_POST['terminoint'][$i]}</td>";
```

Passando seu código pelo 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/84KM9

Comment: Obrigado =). Mas agora o erro mudou kkkk

Comment: provavelmente $teste é uma variável vazia

Comment: $teste estava como $teste = $_POST['interrupcao'];. E coloquei o $teste dentro do for. Agora mudei para: for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($_POST['interrupcao']); $i++) {. E mesmo assim não funcionou. O erro é esse: https://jpst.it/17cdH

Comment: Aí já mudou o problema. Não uso dompdf mas o passo a passo pra resolver isso vale pra todas as ferramentas que convertem html em pdf. Certifique-se que o html gerado pelo php está correto.

Comment: Ok, obrigado =)